# Real-Time GPS Tracker with CartoDB and firebase

Tags: carto, gps, firebase

is it possible to track the gps tracker in cartodb in real time?

I saw that cartodb has table sync but this sync only every hour but i need something that can sync every 30 sec.

Answer (score 1):

You can force sync through the API: https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/sync-tables/

The call should look like:

```
curl -v -X "PUT" "https://{username}.carto.com/api/v1/synchronizations/<import_id>/sync_now?api_key={account API Key}" -H "Content-Length:0"
```

However you need to alter some value server side for a near-real-time experience because the limit is every 900s (15m).

Comment: Thanks, i read about such limitation but i hoped there is another solution